# Window function to drag points on a curve

Tags: javascript, graph, draggable, curve

I want to make an editable curve where the user can drag points up and down. I also want the possibility to drag multiple points at the same time (I'm thinking like the behavior of an equalizer which slide other frequencies as you slide one).
For now i use a linear window function with a certain range but the result is not very smooth. I'd like to know if there is some kind of function to get a smoother result.

[You can see what my linear function looks like here](https://jsfiddle.net/f3rmm82w/)

```
/*Linear triangle function
           ^
    ^      | < value
   /|\     |
  / | \    |
 /  |  \   |
/   |   \  |
---------- | < data[index] 
    ^
  index
<-->
range
*/
```